# Template class throwing error on non-parameterized constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, most-vexing-parse

I have a templated class with a parameterized constructor.

Here's a minimal example.  The following code works fine:

```
template <typename T>
class my_template
{
public:
    my_template () {}
    my_template (T Value) : value(Value) {}
    T get_value () { return value; }

private:
    int value;
};

int main()
{
    my_template<int> int_thing (5);
    my_template<char> char_thing ('a');

    int int_test = int_thing.get_value ();
    char char_test = char_thing.get_value ();
}
```

What doesn't work is if I try using the default constructor.

Changing this line:

```
  my_template<int> int_thing (5);
```

To this:

```
  my_template<int> int_thing ();
```

Throws this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0153   expression must have class type template_class  c:\Nightmare Games\Examples\CPP\template_class\template_class.cpp   39
```

On this line:

```
  int int_test = int_thing.get_value();
```

I haven't the foggiest.  Removing the parameterized constructor from the class has no effect on the error thrown on the other constructor.  C++ just hates that default constructor.

Theoretically, I can just throw some dummy data in the parameter and change it later, so it's not blocking me.

But I just *have* to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a function declaration (see [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse#:~:targetText=The%20most%20vexing%20parse%20is,of%20the%20C%2B%2B%20language%20standard.) for details):

```
my_template<int> int_thing ();
```

You can simply use uniform initialization instead if you have > c++11:

```
my_template<int> int_thing {};
```

Otherwise just remove the parantheses.